Appropriate GPU deepface
I am currently using only CPU(intel-13700K) for deepface to run face recognition.
I have achieved 15 images per second on my dataset; however, striving for more.
I am using a combination of ArcFace + centerface.
I was wondering if there are any basic requirements for the GPU to achieve the best results.
My understanding is that it better be Nvidia but what about the memory?
Does it have to be at least some GB big or anything like that?
I am considering getting RTX 3070.
Also, though I understand no one can give exact figures, but what can I expect in terms of performance compared to doing CPU only right now and getting 15 images/second.
Got 15 images per sec with 13700k CPU.
